# How feasible is this with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to write a Terraform module whose purpose is to add members (users and service principals) to Azure AD groups. Here's my code:

```
# This is our input which contains the display names of users, SPNs and groups

memberships_service_principals = {
    "spn1" = "group1"
    "spn2" = "group2"
}

memberships_users = {
    "user1" = "group1"
    "user1" = "group2"
    "user2" = "group2"
}

# Here we get each SPN's group object ID

data "azuread_group" "groups_service_principals" {

  for_each = var.memberships_service_principals
  display_name = each.value
}

# Here we get each SPN's object ID

data "azuread_service_principal" "service_principals" {

  for_each = var.memberships_service_principals
  display_name = each.key
}

# Here we get each user's group object ID

data "azuread_group" "groups_users" {

  for_each = var.memberships_users
  display_name = each.value
}

# Here we get each user's object ID

data "azuread_user" "users" {

  for_each = var.memberships_users
  user_principal_name = each.key
}

# Here we construct and merge two maps of groups => object IDs

locals {
  service_principal_object_ids = { for k, v in var.memberships_service_principals : data.azuread_service_principal.service_principals["${k}"].object_id => data.azuread_group.groups_service_principals["${k}"].object_id }
  user_object_ids = { for k, v in var.memberships_users : data.azuread_user.users["${k}"].object_id => data.azuread_group.groups_users["${k}"].object_id }
  member_object_ids = merge(local.service_principal_object_ids, local.user_object_ids)
}

# Here we configure the memberships by passing the group and SPN/user object IDs

resource "azuread_group_member" "group_members" {

  for_each = var.member_object_ids
  group_object_id = each.value
  member_object_id = each.key
}
```

Unfortunately, the above code doesn't work because a map in Terraform can have only unique keys. This rule gets violated in these cases:

1. When a user/SPN is specified more than once in order to be member of more than one group
2. Even if the map gets inverted (so as to have groups as keys instead of users/SPNs), group names and IDs are also not unique

I tried to define my input as follows but I still have no idea how to come up with a map of unique keys which to pass to create the memberships via 'resource "azuread_group_member"':

```
locals {
  test_input1 = [
    {principal = "user1", groups = ["group1", "group2"]},
    {principal = "user2", groups = ["group2"]}
  ]
  test_input2 = [
    { "user1" = ["group1", "group2"] },
    { "user2" = ["group2"] }
  ]
}
```

Any help and/or ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your setup, but you could create a map from your variables with unique keys as follows:

```
variable "memberships_users" {
    default = {
        "user1" = "group1"
        "user1" = "group2"
        "user2" = "group2"
    }
}


locals {
    
    service_users = merge([
          for k1,v1 in var.memberships_service_principals:
              {
                  for k2,v2 in var.memberships_users:
                      "${k1}-${k2}" => {
                          memberships_service_principal = k1
                          memberships_service_principal_group = v1
                          memberships_user = k2
                          memberships_user_group = v2                          
                      }
              }
            ]...)
}
```

which gives:

```
service_users = {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  "spn1-user1" = {                          
    "memberships_service_principal" = "spn1"                                                           
    "memberships_service_principal_group" = "group1"                                                   
    "memberships_user" = "user1"                                                                       
    "memberships_user_group" = "group2"                                                                
  }                                                                                                    
  "spn1-user2" = {                          
    "memberships_service_principal" = "spn1"                                                           
    "memberships_service_principal_group" = "group1"                                                   
    "memberships_user" = "user2"                                                                       
    "memberships_user_group" = "group2"                                                                
  }                                                                                                    
  "spn2-user1" = {                          
    "memberships_service_principal" = "spn2"                                                           
    "memberships_service_principal_group" = "group2"
    "memberships_user" = "user1"                                                                       
    "memberships_user_group" = "group2"                                                                
  }                                                                                                    
  "spn2-user2" = {                          
    "memberships_service_principal" = "spn2"                                                           
    "memberships_service_principal_group" = "group2"
    "memberships_user" = "user2"       
    "memberships_user_group" = "group2"
  }
}
```

Then you could use that:

```
# SAMPLE CODE. Its not clear what you wish to accomplish,
# thus some changes probably will be required!
resource "azuread_group_member" "group_members" {
  for_each = local.service_users
  group_object_id = data.azuread_group.groups_service_principals[each.value.memberships_service_principal].object_id 
  member_object_id =data.azuread_group.groups_users[each.value.memberships_user].object_id
}
```

Comment: Hello Marcin! This also doesn't work because the moment you declare a map with duplicate keys, Terraform immediately removes them from and constructs a map with only the unique keys:

```
variable "memberships_users" {
    default = {
        "user1" = "group1"
        "user1" = "group2"
        "user2" = "group2"
    }
}

# echo var.memberships_users | tf console
{
  "user1" = "group2"
  "user2" = "group2"
}
```

Comment: @MrG Why would you define a map with duplicate keys? You have to re-think your design not to have such a possibility.

Comment: This is my input data. I'm trying to think of a way to pre-process it but the more I think, the more I get convinced that this is not something best done in Terraform. Unless I'm missing something (I'm not advanced in HCL)?

Comment: @MrG I showed in the answer how you make keys not unique - by creating composite key.

Comment: Thank you for that. This also won't work as there may be input with only users or only service principals in which case constructing a unique composite key will not be possible.
  Again, I urge you to test declaring an input map with duplicate keys - it will result in skipped input in local.service_users.

Comment: @MrG Usually if you have multiple values for same keys, the values would be a list. So joining variables into one map with duplicate keys, would result in a unique keys where values are list.